# Android restarts App with message "Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 9..."

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

We are developing an app with the following entries in the manifest

```
<uses-sdk
android:maxSdkVersion="18"
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
```

The application receives messages via GCM containing an id, then the app grabs corresponding messages from the app engine via this id.

Some of our customers complain about, messages not being fetched from server
this is some part of the logcat output (sorry, partly german)

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
08-13 21:03:12.605 29031 29031 I dalvikvm: Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 9...
08-13 21:03:12.730 29031 29031 I appX.android.ApagerApp: onCreate() <-------------
08-13 21:03:12.735 29031 29031 W appX.android.ApagerApp: Entwicklereinstellungen AUS
08-13 21:03:12.740 29031 29031 V appX.android.services.C2DMReceiver: Broadcast empfangen.
08-13 21:03:12.740 29031 29031 D appX.android.services.C2DMReceiver: Broadcast: Receive (Nachricht empfangen).
08-13 21:03:12.740 29031 29031 D appX.android.services.C2DMReceiver: LED Einstellung gesetzt, aktiviere LED
08-13 21:03:12.775 29031 29031 V appX.android.services.C2DMReceiver: Starte Verarbeitung der Nachricht.
08-13 21:03:12.775 29031 29031 I appX.android.services.C2DMReceiver: Acquiring cpu wake lock...
08-13 21:03:12.780 29031 29031 I appX.android.services.C2DMReceiver: CPU wake lock acquired
08-13 21:03:12.780 29031 29031 D appX.android.ApagerApp: alarmqueue was null, creating new one
08-13 21:03:12.780 29031 29031 V appX.android.services.GetMessageFromServer: Start now fetching message.
08-13 21:03:12.795 29031 29031 I appX.android.services.GetMessageFromServer: Internetverbindung besteht: true
08-13 21:03:12.795 29031 29031 I appX.android.services.GetMessageFromServer: ConnectionType: MOBILE
08-13 21:03:12.795 29031 29031 I appX.android.services.GetMessageFromServer: Erster Start, setze timestampOfLastAlarm auf aktuelle Systemzeit
08-13 21:03:18.825 29244 29244 I dalvikvm: Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 9...
08-13 21:03:19.010 29244 29244 I appX.android.ApagerApp: onCreate()  <-------------
08-13 21:03:19.015 29244 29244 W appX.android.ApagerApp: Entwicklereinstellungen AUS
```

As you can see, there is this magic line ***Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 9...*** which restarts the app (performs application onCreate())

That's very bad, because at this point the app tries to do the HTTP GET.

Does anybody know what's going on here and produces the restart?
As far as I understand the issue, there are workarounds applied to provide compatibility of a newer android version (running on the phone) to the code it is compiled against right?
How can I fix that? Is it intended to restart the phone?

The class in question is `Java.net.httpurlconnection`, the app seems to restart, when that class comes into play (`HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection()`)

The user's device looks like this:
release: 4.2.2
sdk_int: 17
manufacturer: samsung
model: GT-I9300

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know if it's your issue, but you seem to have your targetSdk and maxSdk attributes confused. You should remove maxSdk, and set your targetSdk to 18.

Comment: Actually it's not, maxSDK is to test compatibility with new android version, before releasing it for that version. Target SDK is not optimal, I admit. That has to do with a 3rd party dependency, but maybe we can get rid of it and build against sdk version 18. The hint says, if I remember correctly, "use the newest sdk version or the first version your app supports"...